# NavLink activeClassName Attribute not working when structure of 'to' attribute is changed

Tags: reactjs, dom, routes, router, nav

We all know that in 'to' we place the route where we wanna go
like

```
<NavLink to={`${option.value}`} activeClassName="active">Click Me <./NavLink>
```

But when I change it to

```
<NavLink to={{
            pathname: `${option.value}`,
            state: {scroll: true}
          }} activeClassName="active">Click Me <./NavLink>
```

It still works fine but now the activeClassName is not working.
The reason to do this is I want the scroll attribute in history when the user clicks on this link.
onClick and another function does not makes this happen because on route change the history gets reset.
Can anyone tell me the solution to this problem, that how can I get the scroll in history and get the activeClassName working as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Navlink inside an < ul> tag;

Here there is an example:

```
      <ul className={classes.sidebarList}>
        {sidebarList.map((sidebarItem, sidebarIndex) => {
          const { ICON } = sidebarItem;
          return (
            <NavLink
              key={sidebarIndex}
              exact
              to={sidebarItem.PATH}
              activeClassName={classes.sidebarActiveLink}
              className={classes.sidebarListItem}
            >
              <ICON
                className={classes.sidebarIcon}
              />
              <div className={classes.sidebarTitle}>{sidebarItem.title}</div>
            </NavLink>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
```

Comment: Dragos UniqQum

activeClassName does not work when we use to={{pathname:'/faq', state:{scroll:false}}}
I am using different sctructure of to attribute in NavLink